# Do lots of fields cause a partial refresh to be slow?

Tags: xpages

I have a lot of fields on a form. Not exactly sure how many but it has to be close to 100, if not over.

I have a change event of one field doing a partial refresh of a computed field with the following formula.

```
return document1.getItemValueString("txtCustomScore");
```

`txtCustomScore` is the field that has the event.

It takes 3-4 seconds to update this field. Are all of those other field somehow affecting how long it takes to refresh this field? It is taking 3-4 seconds.

I even tried  `getValue` instead of `getItemValueString`. As suggested in this thread:
[Setting a document field with replaceItemValue from a rich text control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774972/setting-a-document-field-with-replaceitemvalue-from-a-rich-text-control)

But it still takes 3-4 seconds to update the computed field.

Is there anyway to fix this other than eliminating fields from the form?

Comment: Take a look at this. Partial Execution Mode + the use of execId might help.. http://www.intec.co.uk/partial-execution-mode-probably-the-most-powerful-xpages-feature-you-dont-use/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. Even for a partial refresh all component values get evaluated and the server side result tree is built. As Tommy suggested, partial execution mode might be your answer

Comment: Are you sure? The rendered properties and values of repeat controls and other data containers are recalculated even if not refreshed. But as far as I know is the calculation of the values of labels, computedText, etc. not evaluated if not partially refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly encourage you to watch the XPages Masterclass Video Series 1 (See: http://tonymcguckin.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/xpages-masterclass-series-1/).

From this you will then be able to introspect the XPages Request Processing Lifecycle phases and Profile your application.  This will uncover the exact reasons behind the processing cost.